# Php laravel 5.0 project stops working after I run composer update

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php

My project is in php laravel 5.0 . Now I need to update my facebooksdk version. In order to update that I need to update my `composer.json` file but after running composer update, on opening my web it shows a blank page. However composer update run successfully.

[image]

Comment: Anything in the error log?

Comment: try `php artisan serve` in terminal.. it will show you errors..

Comment: What composer command did you run? `composer require facebook/graph-sdk`? You didn't edit your composer.json file manually, did you? Can you revert everything to the last working commit?

Comment: try this composer dump-autoload

Comment: How about sharing `composer.json` with us?

Comment: @Zaheer Attar yes this is the error..
[Mon Aug 14 12:34:15 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler::createResponse() in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php on line 92

Comment: Yes @sisve I did edit composer.json file manually. I just change the fbsdk version thats it. And this error comes after composer update no matter I edit compser.json or not.

Comment: `composer update` updates _all_ packages. It doesn't care if you only changed one version constraint, it will look at all packages and find all available updates. It looks like you upgraded the symfony/debug package from 2.x to 3.x where ExceptionHandler::createResponse was removed. We could attempt to track down the initial exception, but the problem still exist; you've blindly upgraded packages with the `composer update` command. That is not how you upgrade a single package. Editing composer.json manually is usually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solution work for you:
Remove the `config.php` file from `bootstrap/cache/` path and run command:

```
composer dumpautoload
composer update
```